# window's close button, can't get it to work as i want to?

Tags: winapi, assembly, masm32

I have been facing this problem for quit a while, I want to post a message box when I click on the close button in which wanted to ask if Yes/No question if the user want to close the program. my custom exit button works like a charm but the window's close button(X) isn't so.
when I click on Yes it exit the program perfectly, but when click on No, it just close the window but the program is still running and had to close it from the task manager every time.

Had to mention that just when click the (X) button immediately the program close the main window and prompt the message box (Yes/No).
I just wanted to get it work so when I click on No it will get back to the main program.
this is the code:

```
.386P 
.MODEL FLAT, stdcall
include c:\masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib c:\masm32\lib\user32.lib
include c:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib c:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib c:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib
include MYedit.inc
atodw  PROTO :DWORD
;------------------------------------------------------------
_DATA SEGMENT DWORD PUBLIC USE32 'DATA' 
NEWHWND   DD 0                                          
MSG       MSGSTRUCT <?>                                 
WC        WNDCLASS  <?>                                 
HINST     DD 0                                      
TITLENAME DB 'Calculator',0                         
CLASSNAME DB 'CLASS32',0                                
CPBUT     DB 'Exit',0                                    
CPBUT2    DB 'Calculate',0                              
CPEDT1    DB 'Decimal Number (Max 9 Digits):',0         
CPEDT2    DB 'New Counting Base (1-36):',0
CPEDT3    DB 'Result:',0
CPEDT4    DB 0
CLSBUTN   DB 'BUTTON',0                                 
CLSEDIT   DB 'EDIT',0                                   
HWNDBTN   DWORD 0                                       
HWNDEDT1  DWORD 0                                       
HWNDBTN2  DWORD 0                                   
HWNDEDT2  DWORD 0
HWNDEDT3  DWORD 0                                   
HWNDEDT4  DWORD 0  
HWNDEDT5  DWORD 0 
HWNDEDT6  DWORD 0     
CAP       DB 'Exit',0                           
MES       DB 'Are you sure to exit the program ?',0                 
NStr        DB 9 dup(0),0                               
CBasStr   DB 3  DUP(0),0
CBas        DB ?,0
TheResult BYTE 31 DUP (0),0
_DATA ENDS
;----------------------------------------
_TEXT SEGMENT DWORD PUBLIC USE32 'CODE'
START:
     INVOKE GetModuleHandleA, 0
     MOV  [HINST], EAX 
REG_CLASS:
     MOV [WC.CLSSTYLE], STYLE
     MOV [WC.CLWNDPROC], OFFSET WNDPROC
     MOV [WC.CLSCBCLSEX],0
     MOV [WC.CLSCBWNDEX],0
     MOV EAX, [HINST]
     MOV [WC.CLSHINST], EAX
     INVOKE LoadIconA, 0, IDI_APPLICATION
     MOV [WC.CLSHICON], EAX 
     INVOKE LoadCursorA, 0, IDC_ARROW
     MOV [WC.CLSHCURSOR], EAX 
     MOV [WC.CLBKGROUND], 5  
     MOV DWORD PTR [WC.CLMENNAME], 0
     MOV DWORD PTR [WC.CLNAME], OFFSET CLASSNAME
     INVOKE RegisterClassA, ADDR WC
     INVOKE CreateWindowExA, 0, OFFSET CLASSNAME, OFFSET TITLENAME, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW-WS_SIZEBOX-WS_MAXIMIZEBOX-WS_CAPTION, 100, 100, 500, 160, 0, 0, [HINST], 0
     CMP EAX, 0
     JZ  _ERR
     MOV [NEWHWND], EAX
     INVOKE ShowWindow, [NEWHWND], SW_SHOWNORMAL
;------------------------------------------------------------
     INVOKE UpdateWindow, [NEWHWND] 
MSG_LOOP: 
     INVOKE GetMessageA, OFFSET MSG, 0, 0, 0
     CMP EAX, 0
     JE  END_LOOP
     INVOKE TranslateMessage, OFFSET MSG
     INVOKE DispatchMessageA, OFFSET MSG
     JMP MSG_LOOP
END_LOOP:
     INVOKE ExitProcess, [MSG.MSWPARAM]
_ERR:
     JMP END_LOOP  
; The Order of Parameters in The Stack
; [EBP+014Í]  ; LPARAM
; [EBP+10H]   ; WAPARAM
; [EBP+0CH]   ; MES
; [EBP+8]     ; HWND
WNDPROC  PROC
     PUSH EBP
     MOV EBP,ESP
     PUSH EBX
     PUSH ESI
     PUSH EDI 
     CMP DWORD PTR [EBP+0CH] ,WM_DESTROY
     JE  WMDESTROY
     CMP DWORD PTR [EBP+0CH] ,WM_CREATE
     JE  WMCREATE 
     CMP DWORD PTR [EBP+0CH] ,WM_COMMAND
     JE  WMCOMMND
     JMP DEFWNDPROC

     WMCOMMND: 
         MOV EAX,HWNDBTN
         CMP DWORD PTR [EBP+14H],EAX
         JE WMDESTROY

         MOV EAX,HWNDBTN2
         CMP DWORD PTR [EBP+14H],EAX
         JE BTNCOPY

         MOV EAX, 0
         JMP FINISH
    ;====================================
    BTNCOPY:    
         INVOKE SendMessageA, HWNDEDT4, WM_GETTEXT, 10, OFFSET NStr
         INVOKE SendMessageA, HWNDEDT5, WM_GETTEXT, 3, OFFSET CBasStr
         CALL Calculate
         INVOKE SendMessageA, HWNDEDT6, WM_SETTEXT, 0, OFFSET TheResult
         MOV EAX, 0
         JMP FINISH
    WMCREATE:
        ;=============The Exit Button
         INVOKE CreateWindowExA, 0, OFFSET CLSBUTN, OFFSET CPBUT, STYLBTN, 372, 50, 100, 20, DWORD PTR [EBP+08H], 0, [HINST],0
         MOV HWNDBTN,EAX
        ;=============The Calculate Button
         INVOKE CreateWindowExA, 0, OFFSET CLSBUTN, OFFSET CPBUT2, STYLBTN, 372, 10, 100, 20, DWORD PTR [EBP+08H], 0, [HINST],0
         MOV HWNDBTN2,EAX
;=============================================
        ;1st =====================
         INVOKE CreateWindowExA, WS_EX_RIGHT, OFFSET CLSEDIT, OFFSET CPEDT1, STYLEDT1, 10, 10, 210, 23, DWORD PTR [EBP+08H], 0, [HINST],0
         MOV HWNDEDT1,EAX 
        ;2nd =====================
         INVOKE CreateWindowExA, WS_EX_RIGHT, OFFSET CLSEDIT, OFFSET CPEDT2, STYLEDT1, 10, 50, 210, 23, DWORD PTR [EBP+08H], 0, [HINST],0
         MOV HWNDEDT2,EAX
        ;3rd =====================
         INVOKE CreateWindowExA, WS_EX_RIGHT, OFFSET CLSEDIT, OFFSET CPEDT3, STYLEDT1, 10, 90, 210, 23, DWORD PTR [EBP+08H], 0, [HINST],0
         MOV HWNDEDT3,EAX
        ;4th =====================
         INVOKE CreateWindowExA, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, OFFSET CLSEDIT, OFFSET CPEDT4, STYLEDT2, 225, 10, 83, 20, DWORD PTR [EBP+08H], 0, [HINST],0
         MOV HWNDEDT4,EAx
        ;5th =====================
         INVOKE CreateWindowExA, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, OFFSET CLSEDIT, OFFSET CPEDT4, STYLEDT2, 225, 50, 27, 20, DWORD PTR [EBP+08H], 0, [HINST],0
         MOV HWNDEDT5,EAX 
        ;6th =====================
         INVOKE CreateWindowExA, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, OFFSET CLSEDIT, OFFSET CPEDT4, STYLEDT2, 225, 90, 249, 20, DWORD PTR [EBP+08H], 0, [HINST],0
         MOV HWNDEDT6,EAX
;=================================
         INVOKE SetFocus, HWNDEDT4 
         MOV EAX, 0
         JMP FINISH 
    DEFWNDPROC:
         INVOKE DefWindowProcA, DWORD PTR [EBP+08H], DWORD PTR [EBP+0CH], DWORD PTR [EBP+10H], DWORD PTR [EBP+14H]
         JMP FINISH    
    WMDESTROY: 
         INVOKE MessageBoxA, DWORD PTR [EBP+08H], OFFSET MES, OFFSET CAP, 4
         .IF EAX==6
         INVOKE PostQuitMessage, 0
         MOV EAX,0
         .ELSE
         JMP FINISH
         .ENDIF
    FINISH:
         POP EDI
         POP ESI
         POP EBX 
         POP EBP
         RET 16
WNDPROC ENDP
```

I have taken a picture of the situation but can't add it since don't have enough reputation.
How can i avoid that, and if the myedit.inc or the Calculate PROC are needed just let me know in order to post them for you.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show message box in WM_CLOSE message handler. WM_DESTROY is too late. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Wow man thank you so much, i had to say i opened that link before but didn't get it right, but with your help and my insist to discover managed to get it to work by replacing WM_DESTROY with WM_CLOSE in this line: 
CMP DWORD PTR [EBP+0CH] ,WM_DESTROY
after defining
WM_CLOSE equ 10h
thank you a lot, finally made it

Comment: I have another question which is how to make it possible to change between the three edit tabs that I have in my program using the tab key?